# The relative virtual path "WebSite3" is not allowed here

Tags: sql, database, web-config

```
Configuration rootWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/WebSite3");
```

My project name is WebSite3, however when i try running the code, i get  the relative virtual path "WebSite3"is not allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Configuration rootWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

That should open to the root of your web application.

This is the code I used to test:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "";
    System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationCollection appSettings =
             rootWebConfig.AppSettings.Settings;
    foreach (string key in appSettings.AllKeys)
    {
       Label1.Text += "Name: " + key + " Value: " + appSettings[key].Value + "<br />" ;
    }
 }
```

Which resulted in the following text on my label (Sensitive info blacked out)

[image]

Comment: Have you tested this?  Docs say you need to pass null or a file. Passing "~" is used to return the root folder, not a file.

Comment: Yep.  Code sample added.  This functions perfectly.  Apparently,. I was wrong about passing null.  Passing null opens the configuration for the ***Website***, not the web app.  So it equates to / instead of /~

Comment: I believe the docs are worded in an unfortunately misleading way.  They actually say you need to pass the ***path*** to the file, which could mean the path to the folder containing the configuraiton file.  Their code samples clearly show that they're passing in the relative folder path.  Were they passing in the file name, it should end with .config.

Comment: I believe the doc is both correct and misleading. Passing null does open the root config - root being the top level site, but "the virtual path to the configuration file"? How about "the virtual path to the site where the configuration file resides?" Also note that Microsoft's example looks exactly like the OP's code that doesn't work.

Comment: Good eye - I saw that, too.  (The fact that his code looks like the samples, that is.)  I suspect that the OP's application isn't really "WebSite3", and that a simple typo is causing the issue, but I'm not 100% sure of that. If I'm right, the "~" option should circumvent it.

Comment: Agreed. Also.. Even though the site's name might be Website3 in dev doesn't mean that the site's name will be that in QA, or Prod. Use of the tilde is just plain smart all around.